# Gradually increasing reinforcement learning environment complexity

Tags: references, reinforcement-learning

The problem of robotic arm control has different levels of complexity ranging from simulation to real-world application. For example, a simulation may not model friction of the joints, which becomes important in reality.

Is it possible to use a model trained in a simple environment to bootstrap learning in a more complex environment? Does this have a name? Does it fall under hierarchical reinforcement learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This concept is first presented in "[Curriculum Learning](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Curriculum-learning-Bengio-Louradour/2f84d432e46ed1253764e238e3038c9c791790e7)" by Bengio et at.

From the abstract:

> Humans and animals learn much better when the examples are not
>   randomly presented but organized in a meaningful order which
>   illustrates gradually more concepts, and gradually more complex ones.
>   Here, we formalize such training strategies in the context of machine
>   learning, and call them "curriculum learning".